# python plot integration result , how to do like what Mathematica does

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, scientific-computing, quad

I want to rewrite this Mathematica code into Python, but I was puzzled then, please help me! Thanks a lot. Perhaps the result of an integration is different with array, however, I don' t know!

[IMAGE: mathematica code which I want to rewrite in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzBdt.png)

I was troubled with python code then....

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
import scipy as sp
from pylab import *
#from scipy import *
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad, tplquad

plt.figure('God Bless : fig1')
plt.title(r'fig1_')
plt.xlabel(r'z')
plt.ylabel('$L_0$(erg $s^{-1}$)')
#plt.axis([0,10,-2,2])


Limit = 1.e48
c  = 2.997e10
Om = 0.27
H0 = 70e5/(1.e6*3.86e18) 
z  = np.arange(0,10, 0.01) 
def dLz(z):
  return 1./(1.-Om + Om*(1.+z)**3.)**(1./2)
val, abserr = quad(dLz, 0, 10)
print ("integral value =", val, ", absolute error =", abserr)    
dL     = val
Fmin   = 2.0e-8 
Llimit = 4.0*np.pi*dL**2*Fmin
plt.plot(z, Limit)


plt.savefig('fig_1.eps', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps def dLz(z): return 1/math.sqrt(1+Om*z*(3+z*(3+z)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's it ! Hallelujah !!

```
#-----------  DETERMIN  zimax -------------

Limit = 1.e48
c  = 2.997e10
Om = 0.27
H0 = 70e5/(1.e6*3.86e18) 
Fmin   = 2.0e-8 
z  = np.arange(0,10, 0.1)
def dLz(z):
  return (c/H0)*(1.+z)/(1.-Om + Om*(1.+z)**3.)**(1./2)
x_lower = 0
vals = []
Llimits = []
for x_upper in z :  
  val, abserr = quad(dLz, x_lower, x_upper)
  vals.append(val)
  print ("integral value =", val, ", absolute error =", abserr)
  dL     = val
  Llimit = 4.0*np.pi*dL**2*Fmin
  Llimits.append(Llimit) # add to array
plt.plot(z, Llimits, 'b--' )

# ------------------------------------------
```